# A customized input text box in html/html5

Tags: html, css

Actually, I want to implement a text box as shown in the figure:[image]

I want that the user should be able to enter the number in the required space. Note that it would be transparent so that the background is visible. A solution involving html5 canvas would also be good.

So, is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried? How does your code look? Maybe try regular input fields and css styling.

Comment: it is a simple text box. My problem is to make the text box just a underline rather than the text box.

Comment: Anyways solved now, thanks to Christian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What have you tried so far? You pretty much answered your own question, make the input have a transparent background.

```
input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 20px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wdUp/1/)

Comment: oh silly me, how did I miss this one! Thanks. Actually I knew about transparent, but didn't knew that border:0 & outline:0 work for an input field too. I couldn't remove the outer box in the <input> tag

Answer (score 0):

Set `<input>` border be only bottom side. [Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ijse/8ewq6/), just like your picture shows.