# Textfield with only bottom border

Tags: html, css

How can I create a Text field that has a transparent or no background, no top,left and right border?

I am only using CSS and HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A customized input text box in html/html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528000/a-customized-input-text-box-in-html-html5)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Probably a duplicate of this post: [A customized input text box in html/html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528000/a-customized-input-text-box-in-html-html5)

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input></input>
```

Answer (score 7):

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb83W/)

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="See! ONLY BOTTOM BORDER!" />
</form>
```