# Styling the <hr /> element in css

Tags: css, html

[This is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxy3c.png)

here is the paint image for description

I need to create something like this below.

._____________mytext__________.

Above text in hr will be in center.

Comment: This is not possible with hr element

Comment: It's also ugly. (my opinion).

Comment: That's not what the HR element is for. You should use either a title element or an other element for that.

Comment: Why not use `________` instead?

Comment: try `formset` and `legend`

Comment: The <hr /> tag is an horizontal line and it is used to separate elements insie of the page, it is not possible to insert some words inside of it.

Comment: If you want to accomplish this effect I recommend using the :before and :after tags on the text element.

Comment: May be duplicated with topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528000/a-customized-input-text-box-in-html-html5

Comment: Could you re-word your question please? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rhea Um, what is `formset`?

Answer (score 4):

You can make something like this with `after` pseudo element

```css
hr{
  position: relative;
}

hr::after{
  content: 'Test text';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

EDIT : for have the point at start and end you can't use my method so this will help you :

```css
.separator{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.separator::before,
.separator::after{
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% + 1px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.separator::before{
  left: 0;
}

.separator::after{
  right: 0;
}

.separator__text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">
    <span class="separator__text">Test text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's rather different from what OP describes

Comment: you can also style the border of the `hr` element. `border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid black;`

Comment: @C0dekid yes, it's just a quick code for insert a text centered into hr

Comment: there should be a dot on both side of the hr line.

Comment: @ArunArya Make a picture of what you want please

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman I have added the link. click on this "This is the image link"

Comment: @ArunArya don't forget to click on the check button on the left if this response solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a parent `div`. The idea here is the underline is part of the div, then you create a white underline in the `span` that overlays the `div`s underline:

```css
div {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 8px);
}
span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
.<div><span>My text</span></div>.
```

## Edit

I have added the dot to either side of the `div`, then set the `width` to be slightly smaller than the full width of the container, to take into account the width of the dots.

Comment: there should be a dot on both side of the hr line.

Answer (score 1):

You can create with `<div>`

```
<div class="divider">
<span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Styling for this :

```
.divider {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.divider::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.divider h6 {
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #767676;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 8px 0 7px;
}
```

Comment: there should be a dot on both side of the hr line.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/qcma6zzw/) using `<h1>` and `<span>` tags.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 span {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Title</span></h1>
```

Comment: there should be a dot on both side of the hr line.

Answer (score 1):

```css
hr:before{

  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  content:attr(data-text);
  margin:0 auto;
  top:-12px;
  left:50%;
  padding:0 1%;
}
hr{
  position:relative;
  border-width:2px;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:transparent black black black; 
}
```

```html
<hr data-text='my text'/>
```

Comment: there should be a dot on both side of the hr line.

Comment: @ArunArya please check now

Answer (score 0):

I also would suggest another solution, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Hello Plunker!</p>
    <hr>
  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
/* Styles go here */
p{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YjYKkPxDOtRQzYDJrfmT?p=preview

Comment: Do not use negative values for margin.